# How can I fix this TypeScript types issue with missing property?

Tags: typescript, types

I have the following:

```
interface YAxis {
  ...
  title?: {
    text?: string
    style?: {
      color?: string
      fontSize?: string
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Basically I'm saying in the `ConfigObject` yAxis can be a `single` object or an array of them

```
interface ConfigObject {
  ...
  yaxis: YAxis | YAxis[]
  ...
}
```

The issue is the TS compiler is complaining in VS Code:

`Property 'title' does not exist on type 'YAxis[]`

I can clearly see this property, so not really sure what I'm doing wrong here?

**I've tried**

- Using a single `YAXis` it works for a single object it works fine

but what if I have an Array of YAxis? i.e multiple Y-Axis

I don't want to use `any` as that kind defeats the purpose of `strongly type` with `Typescript`.

**How I"m using it accessing the properties:**

```
setConfig({
  ...config,
  yaxis: {
    ...config.yaxis,
    title: {
      ...config.yaxis.title,
      text: value,
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: How are you using ConfigObject? You are obviously trying to get `.title` from `yaxis`, which doesn't exist if the `yaxis` is an array.

Comment: @ritaj, I'm using it ```setConfig({..,tile: { yaxis.title.text: value }...})```

Comment: Again, what if `yaxis` is an array? Arrays don't have title property/

Comment: Hm.., I read that type as `it's an array of YAxis`, so I presume it would have those properties. Maybe I've completely misunderstood Typescript type system. @ritaj

Comment: `yaxis` property can either be `YAxis` or array of `YAxis`. If it's `YAxis` it does have title property, if it's Array you can't set title property to an array... Only its' elements.

Comment: `let stringOrArray: string | string[]; stringOrArray.toUpperCase()` doesn't make sense, because `['some string']` doesn't have `toUpperCase` function... It's an array, not a string.

Comment: @ritaj, thanks I think I understood what you're saying, now I need to work out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the `setConfig` invocation in a type guard because `yAxis` can be either an array of `YAxis` or an object of `YAxis`.  The two `const config` examples below show how to use both `YAxis` and `YAxis[]` with type saftey.

```
interface YAxis {
  title?: {
    text?: string;
    style?: {
      color?: string;
      fontSize?: string;
    };
  };
}

interface ConfigObject {
  yaxis: YAxis | YAxis[];
}

const config: ConfigObject = {
  yaxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'hello'
    }
  }
};
/*const config: ConfigObject = {
  yaxis: [{
    title: {
      text: 'hello'
    }
  }]
};*/
const value = "hello";

function setConfig(config: ConfigObject) {
  console.log("setConfig");
  console.log(config);
}

if (!Array.isArray(config.yaxis)) {
  setConfig({
    ...config,
    yaxis: {
      ...config.yaxis,
      title: {
        ...config.yaxis.title,
        text: value
      }
    }
  });
} else {
  config.yaxis.forEach(x => {
    console.log("forEach config");
    console.log(x);
  });
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types